# Why am I getting an infinite loop of 0's? (Java)

Tags: java, while-loop, infinite-loop

I asked a question about my code the other day, which was quickly resolved by the incredible community here. However I have encountered a completely separate problem using a re-written version of my code. Here's a description of the program from my previous post.

> I'm trying to write a program that can detect the largest sum that can be made with any subset of numbers in an ArrayList, and the sum must be lower than a user-input target number. My program is working flawlessly so far, with the exception of one line (no pun intended). Keep in mind that this code isn't complete yet too.

My problem with the code now is that after the user inputs a target number, the program outputs an infinite loop of 0's. Even after trying to debug, I still come up with problems. The ArrayList is being applied to the program perfectly fine, but I think I may have a problem somewhere within one of my `while` loops. Any ideas?

Heres the code.

```
import java.util.*;
class Sum{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int temp = 0, target = 1, result = 0, firstIndex = 0, secondIndex = 0;
        String tempString = null;
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<Integer> last = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        System.out.println("Enter integers one at a time, pressing enter after each integer Type \"done\" when finished.\nOR just type \"done\" to use the default list.");
        String placehold = "NotDone";

        while (!placehold.equals("done")){
            list.add(input.nextLine());
            placehold = list.get(list.size() - 1);
        }
        list.remove(list.size() - 1);
        if (list.size() == 0){            //Inserts default list if said list is empty
            list.add("1");
            list.add("2");
            list.add("4");
            list.add("5");
            list.add("8");
            list.add("12");
            list.add("15");
            list.add("21");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
            tempString = list.get(i);
            temp = Integer.parseInt(tempString);     //Changes the items in the list to Integers, which can be inserted into another list and then sorted
            last.add(temp);
        }
        Collections.sort(last);
        System.out.println("Enter the target number");
        target = input.nextInt();
        while (result < target){
            firstIndex = last.size() - 1;
            secondIndex = firstIndex - 1;
            while (last.get(firstIndex) > target){
                firstIndex--;
            }
            if (last.get(firstIndex) + last.get(secondIndex) < result){
                result = last.get(firstIndex) + last.get(secondIndex);
                last.remove(firstIndex);
                last.remove(secondIndex);
                last.add(result);
            }
            else{
                secondIndex--;
            }
            System.out.println(result);
        }  
    }
}
```

And the Output...

> Enter integers one at a time, pressing enter after each integer Type "done" when finished.
>   OR just type "done" to use the default list.
>
> done    //Prompting to use the default list
>
> Enter the target number
>
> 15      //User inputs target number
>
> 0
>   0
>   0
>   0
>   0
>   0
>   ... //And so on

Comment: Have you tried walking through the second while loop line-by-line with a debugger to verify that firstIndex/secondIndex are always correct?

Comment: Actually, I assumed that is wasn't the indexes causing the problem. However, I'll definitely give it a look. Could have been a very stupid assumption on my part.

Comment: So, you have to be getting stuck in the while loop, which means that results is always less than target. Result is always zero... When we look to see where result can change we find it in only one place, and that place is in your if statement. Since result is never changing then that if statement must never be true. So what happens? Since the if statement is false, secondIndex is decremented, then the loop repeats. SecondIndex is then made to equal firstIndex -1, which resets it as it was to begin with. You are stuck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
target = input.nextInt();
```

should be within your loop otherwise the variable will never change and

`while(result<target)` will never turn to false

---

```
while(result<target) {
    target = input.nextInt();
    // otherCoolCode
}
```

Comment: Yep this fixed the loop! Now I just have to figure out why I'm still getting a 0, but I can do that with time. Thanks a ton (also for the "CoolCode" compliment).

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning `target` before the while loop, and you are not altering `target` any way inside the while loop. You need to prompt the user within the while loop. Otherwise, if you set a `target` variable higher than 0, it will be an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in

```
if (last.get(firstIndex) + last.get(secondIndex) < result) {
    ...
}
```

Result is always initialized to zero, so that condition will never be true.
One possible fix is to add an extra condition to handle this initial case:

```
if (result == 0 || last.get(firstIndex) + last.get(secondIndex) < result) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An infinite loop occurs when you have a loop whose condition(s) do not change during an iteration of the loop.

Let's review your loop:

> ```
>    while (result < target){
>         firstIndex = last.size() - 1;
>         secondIndex = firstIndex - 1;
>         while (last.get(firstIndex) > target){
>             firstIndex--;
>         }
>         if (last.get(firstIndex) + last.get(secondIndex) < result){
>             result = last.get(firstIndex) + last.get(secondIndex);
>             last.remove(firstIndex);
>             last.remove(secondIndex);
>             last.add(result);
>         }
>         else{
>             secondIndex--;
>         }
>         System.out.println(result);
>     }
> ```

Your loop will only end if `result` and/or`target` change so that `result < target` is false.

Within your loop you assign to `result` only when `(last.get(firstIndex) + last.get(secondIndex) < result)` is true.  So if that condition is false then result will not change.

You have some additional state that is not in the loop condition itself but is manipulated by the loop: `firstIndex` and `secondIndex`.  Every iteration of the loop you assign to them.  You do have an 'else' clause where you modify `secondIndex` just before printing the current value of `result`, ***however*** you then immediately assign to it at the top of the loop.

This is the crux of your infinite loop *(when `last.get(firstIndex) + last.get(secondIndex) < result` is false)*:

1. `result` doesn't change
2. Your list `last` isn't modified, thus `last.size()-1` and `firstIndex - 1` remain the same
3. You assign `secondIndex = firstIndex - 1;` overwriting the decrement at the end of the loop, thus neither `firstIndex` nor `secondIndex` change

Comment: Actually, result changes in the line `result = last.get(firstIndex) + last.get(secondIndex);` ... It's just that I am only allowing it to change when a change is possible according to the function of my program. Also, reassigning the `secondIndex` is actually possible here, because when a modification is made, then the ArrayList has changed in size, and is not reinitializing to the same index. HOWEVER, I do see the problem that occurs if I DO NOT have any modifications taking place. The modification essentially gets reversed at the beginning of the loop. I think that will solve the "0" problem

Comment: Right: you modify `result` and `last` *only when the condition is true*.  When the condition is false then you have your infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

In this line

```
if (last.get(firstIndex) + last.get(secondIndex) < result) {
```

the sum of both your values will hardly ever be less than result, which is "0".